# Solving $y=2xy'+\tan^{-1}(xy'^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y=2xy'+\tan^{-1}(xy'^2)$$

Using the substitution $y'=p$ gives $ y=2xp+\tan^{-1}(xp^2)$. Now taking differentiate from both sides,

$$dy=2(xdp+pdx)+\frac{p^2dx+2px\;dp}{1+x^2p^4}$$
Dividing by $dx$,

$$p=(2p+\frac{p^2}{1+x^2p^4})+(2x+\frac{2px}{1+x^2p^4})\frac{dp}{dx}$$
$$(p+\frac{p^2}{1+x^2p^4})dx+(2x+\frac{2px}{1+x^2p^4})dp=0$$

$$(pdx+xdp)+xdp+\frac{p^2dx+2px\;dp}{1+x^2p^4}=0$$
$$d(px)+d(\tan^{-1}(xp^2))+xdp=0$$If we integrate the last equation we get

$$px+\tan^{-1}(xp^2)+\int xdp=C$$
But I don't know how to deal with $\displaystyle \int xdp$.

Comment: As you already used, $x\,dp=dy$, and so the circle closes. You can extract $\left(1+\frac{p}{1+x^2p^4}\right)$ as common factor somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @mkcpz I used your method on the deleted answer and solved for $x^2$ in the equation $1+p^4x^2+p=0$. So it is done! You can undelete your answer and edit accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y=2xy'+\tan^{-1}(xy'^2)$$
Change the variable $u=\sqrt x$:
$$y=uy'+\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac {y'^2}4 \right)$$
This is Clairaut's differential equation.
$$y=uy'+f(y')$$

You can read the wiki page on Clairaut equation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation_(mathematical_analysis))

Answer (score 1):

Try to make $\sqrt{x}y'$ a derivative. That is achieved by setting $v(u)=y(u^2)$, that is, $x=u^2$, so that $v'(u)=2y'(u^2)u$ and $v'(u)^2=4xy'(x)^2)$. Inserted into the equation this gives
$$
v(u)=uv'(u)+\tan^{-1}(v'(u)^2/4),
$$
which is now in the form of a Clairaut equation with its regular solutions
$$
v(u)=Cu+\tan^{-1}(C^2/4)
$$
and the singular solutions that solve
$$
0=u+\frac{v'(u)/2}{1+v'(u)^4/16}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Using @mkcpz's suggestion on the deleted answer, from $(p+\frac{p^2}{1+x^2p^4})dx+(2x+\frac{2px}{1+x^2p^4})dp=0$ we have,

$$(p\;dx+2x\;dp)+\frac{d(xp^2)}{1+(xp^2)^2}=0$$
$$\frac{d(xp^2)}{p}+\frac{d(xp^2)}{1+(xp^2)^2}=0$$
$$1+x^2p^4+p=0$$
Which we can solve for $x^2$. Hence the final answer is $${ \begin{cases}{x^2=\dfrac{-(p+1)}{p^4}} \\ {y=2xp+\tan^{-1}(xp^2)}\end{cases} }$$